# Migrating to Typescript from React.Js New to TS learning as I go

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, frontend, typescript-typings

I have 2 errors that say the exact thing and I can figure out what I need to place for them to be correct and clear up.

Error:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'never'.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    // @ts-expect-error -- TODO: Variable 'cities' implicitly has type 'any[]' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.
    const cities = [];
    selectedStates.forEach((state) =>
      cities.push(...getCityByState(state.value).map((city) => city.name)) // Error on .value
    );
    // @ts-expect-error -- TODO: Variable 'cities' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.
    setCities(cities);
  }, [selectedStates]);
```

The Error is for the .value in the middle line. (state.value), just the .value gives me the error though.

Here is the other area I get the same Error:

```
  const getSearchQuery = (zipCodes: string[]) => {
    let query = Default_Search + `sort=breed:${selectedSort.value}&`;
    query += selectedBreeds
      .map((breed) => `dogBreeds=${breed.value}&`) //Error .value
      .join("");
    query += zipCodes.map((zipcode) => `zipCodes=${zipcode}&`).join("");
    return query + `ageMin=${minAge.value}&ageMax=${maxAge.value}&`;
  };
```

I get the Error on this one with .value on the middle line again. (breed.value), just the .value gives me the error though.

I am not sure what I am missing with setting this type.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign type to state, like,

```
const type State = {
  value: string;
}

const type City = {
  name: string;
}

useEffect(() => {
  const cities = [] as City[];
  selectedStates.forEach((state: State) =>
    cities.push(...getCityByState(state.value).map((city: City) => city.name)))
setCities(cities);
}, [selectedStates]);
```

This is typescript, so you have to assign type to the variable; otherwise, it'll give errors like this.

You have to do the same for the second one.

Comment: I believe that it is better (and bit safer) to type it as:

`const cities:City[] = [];`

Comment: Yes, you can assign type like that as well and it's better way, too. But all I'm trying to say that you should assign types to variables.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting those errors because of two things:

1. You probably declared the variable "state" as an empty Object;
   So, the type inference can't do its magic because there's not much information about "state".
2. You didn't make a type declaration for "state". That's conflictive for TS when trying to access properties that only you as dev know will populate your object such as "value".

How to solve it?

```
type City = {
  name: string;
  ...etc
}

type State = {
  value: Array<City>;
}

useEffect(() => {
  const cities:Array<string> = []; /*You will be populating this arr with names of cities */
  selectedStates.forEach((state: State) =>
  cities.push(...getCityByState(state.value).map((city: City) => city.name)))
  setCities(cities);
}, [selectedStates]);
```